# Qual a diferença entre Django e Flask

Tags: python, django, flask

Qual a diferença entre as framework Django e flask seus benefícios e qual esta sendo mais utilizada atualmente no mercado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Flask

O Flask é um web framework de código aberto lançado em 2010 amplamente utilizado para Python. Seu funcionamento é semelhante a um conjunto de Lego, onde os desenvolvedores podem construir o que quiserem, tornando o Flask fácil de entender e usar.

### Características:

**Velocidade**
Embora a velocidade não tenha sido muito considerada durante a fase de desenvolvimento do Flask, para o usuário, é uma característica fundamental. O Flask segue uma abordagem de design minimalista e, portanto, tem um desempenho mais rápido em relação ao Django. Ele pode suportar centenas de consultas por segundo sem nenhum impacto negativo.

**Simplicidade**
Devido ao fato de ser minimalista, o Flask fornece ao desenvolvedor os recursos necessários para criar um protótipo para sua aplicação web facilmente. Ele oferece aos desenvolvedores controle e flexibilidade para o desenvolvimento. Existem vários templates disponíveis com a biblioteca de linguagem padrão Jinja2. Além disso, o aplicativo vem com a biblioteca WSGI toolkit e um servidor web embutido para que você não precise depender de servidores externos, como o Apache, para testar seu aplicativo.

**Facilidade de integração com banco de dados**
Ao contrário de outros web frameworks, o Flask não tem uma camada adicional de acesso ao banco de dados nem depende do ORM (Object-Relational Mapping). Como resultado, a integração com toolkits de banco de dados como SQLAlchemy, NoSQL, MongoDB e DynamoDB é bem fácil.

## Django

Django foi lançado em 2005 e é destinado a grandes aplicações. Inclui um ORM, que permite alternar rapidamente entre vários bancos de dados relacionais. Ele ainda fornece MVC e Django REST Framework.

### Características:

**‘Browsable’ API**
O Django REST Framework suporta REST-Ful API e um modelo de API com usuário embutido, para autorização e autenticação. Assim, ele suporta saída HTML amigável quando este formato é solicitado. Essas páginas permitem que desenvolvedores navegam mais facilmente e execute comandos GET e POST de forma simples. A ‘Bromsable’ API é construída com Bootstrap, tornando a customização simples.

**Gestão de banco de dados simples**
Como o Django inclui um ORM, ele permite que vários bancos de dados relacionais, como PostgreSQL, Oracle, MySQL, SQLite etc, interajam com os dados do aplicativo. O Django permite modelos e fácil criação de tabelas e campos automaticamente. Além disso, alterações como a criação de tabelas e índices são implementadas com um único comando.

**Painel de administração usual**
O Django vem com um painel de administração automático e muito personalizável. Este painel facilita a produção e o desenvolvimento de um CMS (sistema de gerenciamento de conteúdo).

Bibliografia:

[H. Fatima, **Flask x Django**. iMasters](https://imasters.com.br/back-end/flask-x-django-como-escolher-o-framework-correto-para-seu-aplicativo-web)